# Do you consider session replication as a security risk?

Tags: security, session

Do you consider session replication as a security risk? I mean if an attacker manages to hijack the session, he would still be able to use the same valid session, especially in scenarios where the session do not expire until one manually logs out. What recommendations would you give to prevent session replication?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have a rolling Session ID - every so often (e.g. after a certain number of requests or a certain short time period), the system generates a new Session ID.

To prevent errors with race conditions due to one resource request causing a new Session ID to be generated, both the current and the previous Session IDs should be accepted during the rollover interval.

In essence, this will cause one of the valid sessions (either the attacker's or the victim's) to expire within their browser as they are using the old Session ID and have not received the cookie containing a new ID.

You should display a message saying something along the lines of **You have been logged out as your account is used elsewhere**. If this happens to be the attacker's machine, then great - you have prevented an attack. If this happens to be the victim's machine at the very least they are aware that their session has been compromised and can take steps to inform the site owners.

If you also combine this with invalidating all existing session for the account upon user login, the victim user logging in again will kick the attacker out and the attacker will need to reacquire a valid Session ID. This should reduce the attack window significantly allowing the system to remain secure while the Session ID leak is investigated and fixed.

Comment: Okay! But when the attacker is using a valid session and then after a short period a new session is generated, won't that new session ID be generated both at attacker's end and victim's end? I wonder if the session can be tied up with the browser instance to make it unique, meaning if the session is replicated it wouldn't work on a different browser/machine. So even if the application allows multiple sessions to be run, each session will only be valid on that particular browser or machine. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Well the `Set-Cookie` header will only be sent once by the server, so only one client will receive the new Session ID.

Comment: Okay, makes sense. Could you please tell me if there's a way to make session unique for each browser?

Comment: Maybe that could be a new question? If it's in a technology I'm familiar with maybe I can answer it. You can always link to your question here to provide context.

Answer (score 0):

Sessions are a better idea when you don't want the client to have the ability to mess with the data.

For example using a session variable to store the User ID of the current user is alright.

So, Session is always a good idea to use it. But it depends how you manage it. (unsetting once used it)

But if you use Cookies it is not recommended as it is stored in the user's computer, it can be modified, viewed by the user itself.