# Does Forms Authentication protect from session hijacking?

Tags: asp.net, security, forms-authentication

I have ASP.NET MVC app that uses Forms Authentication. After user is authenticated, in response he will receive forms cookie that contains auth information. Now regarding the forms cookie: It is encrypted by a machine key and it is protected from tampering by signature. I also use HTTPS... However, what if somehow I get the cookie and try to make request from another client (meaning that the request will be made from another IP address)?

It seems to me that this scenario will work. Are there any ways to defend from this kind of attack?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do you consider session replication as a security risk?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22806797/do-you-consider-session-replication-as-a-security-risk)

Comment: You said, "this scenario will work.". How do you get someone's form id when https/ssl is used?

Comment: [PingPong] I think this could be done using XSS (even if cookie has Secure property set). There may be other things like trojans.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using HTTPS everywhere on your site and set requireSSL="true" on your system.web/authentication/forms element in web.config, you are instructing the browser to only pass that cookie back over an HTTPS connection.  This will protect against the vast majority of traffic sniffing-based session hijacking attacks and you should definitely use it if your site is HTTPS only.

Forms Authentication is inherently stateless.  The server is encrypting the following information and storing it client-side: CookiePath, Expiration, Expired, IsPersistent, IssueDate, Name, UserData, Version.  Assuming your machineKey hasn't been compromised, the client will just see this as a blob of encrypted data.  When it presents that blob to the server again, the server decrypts it and converts it back into a FormsAuthenticationTicket, validates the fields in the ticket against config, verifies that the ticket isn't expired, etc. and decides whether to treat the request as authenticated.  It doesn't 'remember' anything about which tickets are outstanding.  Also note that it doesn't include the IP address anywhere.

The only real attack vector I can think of if you are HTTPS-only, take care to protect your machineKey, and set the forms auth cookie to requireSSL would be for an attacker to target the client's browser and/or computer.  Theoretically they could steal the cookie from memory or disk out of the browser's space.  It might be possible for a virus/trojan to do this or even a malicious browser extension.  In short, if a user could get their hands on a valid, non-expired Forms Auth cookie, they could present it from any machine they wanted to until it expired.  You can reduce the risk here by not allowing persistent auth cookies and keeping your timeouts to a minimum.

If they had the machineKey, they could create FormsAuth cookies from scratch whenever they wanted to.

Oh.. Can't forget Heartbleed.  If you had a load balancer or reverse proxy that was using an insecure version of OpenSSL, it's possible an attacker could compromise your private key and intercept traffic over HTTPS connections.  ASP.NET doesn't use OpenSSL, so you're safe from this in a pure-MS stack.  If you ever hear anything about a vulnerability in MS' SSL implementation, you'd want to patch it ASAP and get your passwords changed and certificates re-issued.

If you are concerned about the browser/machine based hijacking, you might want to take a look at a project I started [and abandoned] called Sholo.Web.Security (https://github.com/scottt732/SholoWebSecurity).  It's goal was to strengthen Forms Authentication by maintaining state on the server at the expense of some overhead on each request.  You get the ability to do things like revoke tickets server-side (kick/logout a user) and prevent users from moving tickets between IP addresses.  It can get annoying in the traveling mobile user scenario that Wiktor describes (it's optional).  Feel free to fork it or submit pull requests.

The Anti-CSRF features that 0leg refers to apply to the UI/form mechanism that initiates the login process, but to my knowledge there is nothing in the Forms Authentication process itself that relates to CSRF.  That is, once the cookie is issued to the client, the only thing protecting it from being bounced between servers is the fact that cookies are restricted to the domains/subdomain they were issued for.  Your stackoverflow.com cookies won't be presented to serverfault.com.  The browser takes care of that stuff for you.

Answer (score 0):

> Are there any ways to defend from that kind of attacks?

You shouldn't. Years ago we have had implemented such feature and abandoned it soon. It turned out that:

- a single user making requests from the very same browser/machine but switching between http/https can sometimes be seen from different IP adresses
- a single user traveling and using her mobile phone sometimes makes consecutive requests from different IP addresses when her phone switches between BTSes

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify the terminology, session hijacking is usually referred to the vulnerability where an unauthorized user accesses the session state on the server.

Authentication cookies are different from session cookies.  ASP.NET puts a great deal more precautions in safeguarding authentication cookies.  What you describe is better described by the term [CSRF](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29) (Cross Site Request Forgery).  As @Wiktor indicated in his response, restricting access by IP is not practical. Plus, if you read how CSRF works, the exploit can run in the user browser from the original IP address.

The good news is that ASP.NET MVC has built in support for CSRF prevention that is pretty easy to implement.  Read [here](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/preventing-cross-site-request-forgery-%28csrf%29-attacks).

Comment: I don't think the OP means CSRF as they specifically state that the cookie is used from another client and IP. Session hijacking can either mean accessing the server session (.NET `Session` object) or stealing the authentication set in place by Forms Authentication. Both are usually achieved by using a valid token client side from the attacker's own system.