# how to prevent cookie from being stolen and user on other browser and system

Tags: javascript, php, security, cakephp, cookies

currently  I'm working with **cakephp** and implementing user management in my project.
today, i came across an issue in user  **session**. 
i have generated a cookie to remember user's password in encrypted format 
The **cookie restores session** if users session goes expired.
now i have tried transferring cookie to other browser from chrome to Mozilla 
using a **cookie manager** plugin. 
and i have found myself logged in in both browser what is the best way to prevent this.
??

Comment: If your "remember-me" token is md5 of IP address then it's predictable. You should combine several bits of data before generating the token. `md5($useragent.$ip)` at the least, still predictable.

Comment: in a country like  India ip of a user changes every time he connect to internet... then he will be logged out every time..

Comment: Oh yeah, IP is often used in session token generation. For remember-me, something like `md5($email.$hashed_password.$useragent)` is a better start.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do you consider session replication as a security risk?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22806797/do-you-consider-session-replication-as-a-security-risk)

Answer (score 2):

You can't prevent this. However, you can reduce the problem by having a session value **generated server-side** when the user starts a new session, which is some hash made from

- The session ID
- The user agent (attacker would have to use/spoof the same client)
- Possibly the IP (would only work for fixed devices, but makes it much harder for an attacker)

Now when a logged in user tries to view a page requiring you to be logged in, you can compare more details than just the session lookup.

It's not impossible to spoof, but this reduces the problem.
This hash should never be actually sent to the client, just kept in the session information server-side.

Comment: how facebook  is doing this ??

Comment: Facebook is using [Symb](http://games.symbiant.cz/projects/symb/symb.php)-like system to store cookies.