# How to prevent replay attack if attacker steals whole cookie?

Tags: security, cookies, encryption, hash, replay

I'm talking about authentication on the web. What if attackers grabs the whole cookie of a victim(let's say over insecure/broken WiFi) on non https, and then accesses the site *before* the victim. How do you counter that?

Comment: There is no way to prevent this type of man-in-the-middle interception of session information and session stealing using non-encrypted links.  Indeed, it was the Firesheep plugin for Firefox that finally forced Facebook, Google, etc to start using TLS/SSL full-time because of open WiFi hot-spots.  (Of course then the NSA got caught doing the same on wired links).  The proper counter is *authenticated* encryption of the session end-to-end.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about [information security](http://security.stackexchange.com) without involving programming.

Comment: Well, alright mates.

Comment: You could implement [rolling session IDs](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22833723/413180). However, this should be in addition to HTTPS only along with "secure" cookie flag and possibly HSTS.

Comment: I've already got HTTPS, and I'm using a Auth library of mine, and I wanted to expand it in a way with nonces to avoid session hijacking attacks over insecure protocols. I know that auth digest mechanism implements a replay prevention, even if carried out on insecure channel, so I thought I could do the same. Gonna look more into it, how is it exactly done with the aforementioned.